# Map with raw generic not accepting parameter with specified generic

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to have a map containing multiple maps. Each of those submaps contain a Set of type Domain. However, I cannot give to the super-map maps containing domains with a specific Domain (e.g.: Domain).

```
Domain<Spell> spells = new Domain<>("spells");

Map<String, Domain> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(spells.getName(), spells);

Map<String, Domain<Spell>> library = new TreeMap<>();
library.put(spells.getName(), spells);

Map<String, Map<String, Domain>> mapLibrary = new TreeMap<>();
mapLibrary.put("test", library);
```

However I get the following error at the last line of code:

```
The method put(String, Map<String,Domain>) in the type Map<String,Map<String,Domain>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Map<String,Domain<Spell>>)
```

How can I do it so that I could have a super-map containing maps with multiple different Domain with different generic parameters?

Additional info: there are four classes that extend Magic:

```
- Spell extends Magic<Spell>
- Prayer extends Magic<Prayer>
- Mental extends Magic<Mental>
- Elemental extends Magic<Elemental>
```

The superclass has a generic parameter since it contains the Domain of which it is part, and as of such must specify the correct type of Domain.

Edit about the duplicate: As said above and in the comments, I seek to **find a workaround** to the issue, not to know why. The answers to the other question simply tell why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: The accepted answer does indeed explain why it causes an error but it does not offer a workaround.

Comment: Have you tried not using a raw type in `Map<String, Map<String, Domain>>`?

Comment: Yes I have tried. I have tried using `Map<String, Map<String, Domain<? extends Magic>>>` to no avail.

Comment: Do not forget the `? extends` in library an map declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Domain<?>>> mapLibrary = new TreeMap<>()`

The error message has told you that `Map<String, Domain<Spell>>` is not assignable to `Map<String, Domain>`. This is what @john16384 commented, `List<Dog>` is not `List<Animal>`. But `List<Dog>` is `List<? extends Animal>`. So your should declare your generic as `Map<String, Map<String, ? extends Domain<?>>`.